# hyperledger-fabric 1.1 unable to install jq

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I have been trying to add the third organization into already existing channel using ./eyfn.sh up script in first network .However Jq installation fails as follows :

```
Installing jq
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

How do you resolve this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

```
Step 1:

Before you pull up docker-compose.yml add extra hosts in your cli container
(This will configure hosts in the container in addition to default)

 extra_hosts:
      - "proxy.xxx.com:ipAddress Of proxy"

Step 2 :

create an apt.conf file in your local directory mentioning your proxy in format :



 Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy.company.com:80/";
    Acquire::https::proxy "http://proxy.company.com:80/";
    Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://proxy.company.com:80/";
    Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://proxy.company.com:80/";

copy this file  from local directory to your cli using command :

docker cp apt.conf <containerId>:/etc/apt
```